# Probability of event x times over n trials [explanation needed]

Tags: probability

I'm in disagreement with someone (which I'm sure is the origin of many posts here):

In *Pokémon GO*, an item called incense will generate 90~110 Pokémon over an hour duration (we'll say exactly `100` for simplicity). A Pokémon inherently has a (derived) `1:500` chance of being what's known as "`shiny`" (basically pallet swapped).

Our debate is over how to calculate the probability of getting a single shiny from a single incense.

I assume the following is correct (and experience would seem to bear it out):
$$P_x = {P_{shiny}}^x(1-{P_{shiny}})^{n-x} = \frac{1}{500}(499/500)^{99} = .0016…$$

Yet, my friend argues:
$$1-\biggl(1-\frac{1}{500}\biggl)^{100} = .1814…$$

Please help me explain **why** his method isn't correct, because I actually can't; Aside from the outlandish and obviously incorrect answer, it *seems* a perfectly valid way to calculate the probability of an event occurring as derived from the chances of it not occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of you are correct. What your friend does is to first find the probability that none of them are shiny and then subtracts from $1$ but that gives probability of at least $1$ shiny, not *exactly one shiny*.

What you do is correct but you forget to multiply by $100$ or ${100 \choose 1}$ as any of the $100$ Pokeman could be shiny.

So the correct probability should be,

$ \displaystyle 100 \cdot \frac{1}{500} \cdot \left(\frac{499}{500}\right)^{99} $

Comment: You have ignored the possibility of two or more shiny Pokemon.  If you include it then you get very close to the friend's answer (a Poisson approximation to the binomial)

Comment: @Henry Question says _single_ shiny. That is what I have explained in the answer.

Comment: Forgive me, but doesn't the ×100 simply bring the decimal to a percentage? And are you sure his calculation of 18% is for one or more shiny? The odds of multiples become increasingly insignificant over time, yes? It just seems like a *huge* jump.

Comment: @DKqwerty in percentage it is $16.4 \%$. Yes his calculation is for one or more shiny. $P(s = 0) + P(s=1) + P(s = 2) + P (s = 3) + P(s = 4) + .. + P(s = 100) = 1$. So when you do $1 - P(s = 0)$, that gives you $P(s = 1) + P(s = 2) + ...P (s = 100)$

Comment: @DKqwerty The $100$ deals with the issue that it could be the first or second or ... $100$th which is the shiny one.  The probability of two is $\frac{100\times 99}{1\times 2} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{500}\right)^2\cdot \left(\frac{499}{500}\right)^{498}$, of three $\frac{100\times 99\times 98}{1 \times 2\times 3} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{500}\right)^3\cdot \left(\frac{499}{500}\right)^{497}$ and so on.  Add these up and you get $0.1814 \ldots$

Comment: Okay, starting to make sense: you're saying I'm calculating the chances of first getting a shiny and then no more (so essentially, order matters), while you're taking order out of the picture (as it should be)?

Comment: @DKqwerty yes you are basically stating that one _specific_ Pokeman (first or second ...) out of $100$ is shiny instead of any _one_ of them could be shiny

Comment: Okay, thank you!! But: now he's saying it can just be done as ``1/500^100``…???

Comment: Sorry, ``1/500*100``.

Comment: :) you mean $\frac{100}{500}$?

Comment: He was of course implying when x and n lie, but yes, lol. 
Hopefully last question: the part you added to my equation, the divisor is obviously $x!$, but how is the numerator described in the basic function?

Comment: @DKqwerty sorry I did not understand your question. Is your question about terms ${100 \choose 1}, {100 \choose 2}... etc$?

Comment: @DKqwerty and you can ask as many related questions that you have. There is no problem at all. If there are more questions, we may have to move the discussion to chat.